# Call method c# with object sender and EventArgs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, methods

How can I call the following method manual?

```
  private void NetworkResponseReceived(object sender, Network.ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
  {
         ExecuteTask();
  }
```

with something like:

```
NetworkResponseReceived();
```

what needs to be inserted within the parentheses?

Comment: NetworkResponseReceived(this, EventArgs.Empty);

Comment: I think the point that tim is making is that if you have code that needs to run in the event handler and outside it, factor it out into a separate method then call the method from both places

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Obviously you can call it this way

```
NetworkResponseReceived(null, new ResponseReceivedEventArgs());
```

But it would be lie. Handler expects that response is received (from some object), which is not true. I think it's better to extract handler's logic into separate method. And call that method both from your code and from handler. Like this:

```
void NetworkResponseReceived(object sender, Network.ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // this method can have some arguments, if needed
    DoSomethingBusinessRelated();
}
```

And simply call same method, from other place:

```
DoSomethingBusinessRelated();
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
NetworkResponseReceived(null, new Network.ResponseReceivedEventArgs());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this;

```
NetworkResponseReceived(null, new ResponseReceivedEventArgs());
```